# NHibernate: Reverse Exists Criteria

Tags: sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I'm querying `Foo`. `Foo` doesn't have an `IList<FooBar>` property (unfortunately). `FooBar` has a `Foo` property (but not a `Bar`), Bar has an `IList<FooBar>`. I need all the `Foo`s where exists a `FooBar` which has a corresponding `Bar` with that `Bar`'s `Date` field equal to today.

I'm not really a pro with Criteria API, but it's not my choice to use it or not.

---

**Edit:** I tried the same with the `QueryOver` API and got this far:

```csharp
 var q1 = session.QueryOver<Foo>()
                 .WithSubquery.WhereExists<Bar>(
                     session.QueryOver<Bar>()
                            .Where(b => b.Date == DateTime.Today)
                            .JoinQueryOver<FooBar>(b => b.FooBars)
                            .Where(fb => fb.Foo == /*???*/ ))
                 .List<Foo>();
```

What do I write in the place of `/*???*/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early disclaimer - I do not have NHibernate installed right now, so this is untested, but I would approach it with something like this:

```csharp
var foos = session.CreateCriteria<Bar>("bar")
                      .CreateCriteria("FooBars", "foobar")
                      .Add(
                         Restrictions.Eq(
                            "bar.Date", 
                            DateTime.Today.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                         ))
                      .SetProjection(Projections.Property("foobar.Foo"))
                      .List<Foo>();
```

Comment: Wait... FooBar doesn't have Bar association, I explicitly said it

Comment: Woops, I missed that...out of curiosity, is there a reason you have join tables that don't actually...you know...join anything?

Comment: They join, in the other direction. Bar->FooBars->Foo

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Is there a reason the query couldn't just be reversed then? I'll update my answer to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: aside from the strange fact that this query returns proxies where all my other queries returned real objects this works quite fine! accepted.